# The image turns black when I use the mouse to rotate it

Tags: graphics3d

All, This code

```
Show[
 ContourPlot3D[{x == 0, y == 0, z == 0},
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3},
  ContourStyle -> {Opacity[0.8]},
  Mesh -> {Range[-3, 3, 1], Range[-3, 3, 1], Range[-3, 3, 1]},
  Lighting -> "Neutral",
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
  Ticks -> {Range[-3, 3, 1], Range[-3, 3, 1], Range[-3, 3, 1]},
  FaceGrids -> {{{0, 0, -1}, {Range[-3, 3], Range[-3, 3]}}},
  ViewPoint -> {3, 1, 2}],
 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Dashed, Blue]],
   Opacity[0.8], White, Cuboid[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, -1, 2}}],
   Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{1, -1, 2}]}]
 ]
```

runs fine on my MacBook Pro (10.10.3) using Mathematica 10.1.0.0. However, when I use my mouse to rotate the image a bit, here is what happens to the image.

[image]

I've reported this as a bug to Mathematica, but am interested if this same black image results on anyone else's machine when they rotate the image a number of times.

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: No problems on my Windows8/V10 platform. Did you try a graphics driver update?

Comment: No problems on *Mathematica* 10.1 on a Mac Pro running OS X 10.7.4.

Comment: I fixed an error in my original post. I should have said I am running OS X 10.10.3. The error still exists, I am just saying that I said I was on OS X 10.3.3, which was a mistake, as I am on OS X 10.10.3.

Comment: I get random black regions on OS X 10.10.3, V10.1, too, and not just on graphics.  It usually reminds me to save my work asap.  On V10.0, crashes were much more frequent, while rotating 3D graphics.  It is random, though.  Your example does not turn black for me, at least not right now.

Comment: Not only does it turn black, when I delete the image and run the code, it comes up black. When I delete the black image and quite the kernel, then run the code, it comes up black. When I delete the image, save the file, quit Mathematica, then open Mathematica and open the file again, when I run the code and window comes up with a whole bunch of stuff saying a big report is going to Mathematica. Just experimented again, rotating eventually produces a black image again.

Comment: No problems on *Mathematica* 10.1 on a PC running Windows 7 (64bit)

Comment: @MichaelE2: An automatic report was sent by my machine to Wolfram due to this error. Is it stored on my machine? If so, do you know where I can find it?

Comment: Diagnostic reports due to crashes (sent to Apple, not Wolfram, I believe) may be found in /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports.  Perhaps that's what you want.  Otherwise, I don't think I know.

Comment: @David I would suggest contacting Wolfram support through email ... for the least they can point you in the right direction (like display driver, etc ... )

Comment: Found this: [http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12402](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12402), then SystemInformation[], followed by External Compilers, revealed CCompilerDriver not loaded. Then there is a Load button. Should I push it? Or wait til tomorrow when I can call Wolfram support?

Comment: Now I found this: [http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/system-requirements.html](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/system-requirements.html). At the bottom of the page it say this: "To use the C compilation feature in Mathematica, a C compiler is required to be present." And I just remember that Command Line Developer Tools OS 10.10 was just updated May 20.

Comment: @MichaelE2: have a little more information. I went to my office machine (IMac OS X 10.10.3) that is running Mathematica 10.0.2.0 and there was no problem running the code. The images did not crash when rotated. I then updated the Command Line Tools (OS X 10.10), then shut the computer down. Turned the computer back on and ran the code again. Once again, no problem rotating the images. They did not crash.

Comment: I am running a similar setup to yours (Macbook Pro 15 with Nvidia 750m late 2013, MacOS X 10.10.3 (all updates including command line tools installed), Mathematica 10.1) and I do not have any problems with rendering the Graphics object appropriately. To the compiler stuff: Your code does not involve compilation of any kind of code, so I do not see why you would need a working CCompiler setup.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Wolfram Support and they recommended that I reinstall Mathematica, following these directions:

http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12473

It seems to have worked. Rotated images are no longer turning black.

We'll see how it goes in the future.

D.