# Rotating a Glow Image

Tags: plotting

This code:

```
ContourPlot3D[{x + y - 2 z == 4, 2 x - y + z == 5}, {x, -3, 
  3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3},
 ContourStyle -> {{Opacity[0.75], Glow[LightBlue], 
    Black}, {Opacity[0.75], Glow[Yellow], Black}}
 ]
```

Produces this image.

[image]

Now, the colors are bright and they don't change color as I rotate the image, but it seems that rotating this image is much slower than rotating the image with this code:

```
ContourPlot3D[{x + y - 2 z == 4, 2 x - y + z == 5}, {x, -3, 
  3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}]
```

Is there a reason that the rotation with the mouse is slower? It also worries me that the blackening of the image issue might occur.

**Update**: Yep, this code:

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{s, 2 t, s + 2 t}, {s, -4, 4}, {t, -4, 4},
  PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.75], Glow[Yellow]},
  Mesh -> None],
 Graphics3D[{
   PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0, 0}],
   Blue, Thick,
   Arrowheads[0.04],
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}}],
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 2}}],
   Red,
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}],
   {Dashed, Line[{{1, 0, 1}, {1, 2, 3}, {0, 2, 2}}]}
   }], PlotRange -> 4
 ]
```

A little later in the day, rotation caused Mathematica to produce this image.

[image]

The only way to cure this problem is to quit Mathematica and start anew.

Comment: Have you considered that it might be `Opacity` and not `Glow` that is slowing down the plot? Also I don't know what you mean by "the blackening of the image issue".

Comment: @Rahul The blackening of the image issue can be seen [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84058/the-image-turns-black-when-i-use-the-mouse-to-rotate-it).